# Using "continue" in array mapping if contains empty array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm filtering in a 2D array where I only want to get the result if there are any values in each section.

### My struct:

```
struct SectionObject: Comparable {
    var sectionName: String
    var sectionObjects: [SectionValues]
    
    static func < (lhs: TagObjects, rhs: TagObjects) -> Bool {
        return lhs.sectionName < rhs.sectionName
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: TagObjects, rhs: TagObjects) -> Bool {
        return lhs.sectionName == rhs.sectionName
    }
}
```

In my extension of searchBarDelegate I'm filtering the objects by:

```
//var filterArray: [SectionObject]

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        filterArray = sectionsArray
        return
    }
        
        
    filterArray = sectionsArray.map({
        let existingValues = $0.sectionObjects.filter({ $0.value.contains(searchText) })
        // if existingValues.count == 0 { continue }
        return SectionObject.init(sectionName: $0.sectionName, sectionObjects: existingValues)
    })
}
```

It's working as I want it, but sometimes the result can be 0 (and not nil), so I can't be using the `compactMap` to skip the section.

I can solve this by just filtering again where `sectionObjects.count != 0`, but I wonder if it's possible in any way to just include the `continue` in the array mapping?

Comment: Unrelated but never check `.count == 0`. There is an optimized property `.isEmpty`. And why do you name your properties with redundant *section* prefix? According to the naming guidelines ***omit words that merely repeat type information***

Comment: @vadian I just renamed it for this case. I'm using better naming in my own code :) But thanks for the first notice with the `.isEmpty`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use `compactMap`! Just return `nil` instead of `continue`:

```
filterArray = sectionsArray.compactMap({
    let existingValues = $0.sectionObjects.filter({ $0.value.contains(searchText) })
    if existingValues.isEmpty { return nil }
    return SectionObject.init(sectionName: $0.sectionName, sectionObjects: existingValues)
})
```

This works because `compactMap` will remove those elements that are mapped to `nil`.